# Is it possible to determine what command line arguments were passed to a Windows executable?

Tags: windows, debugging, arguments

In a unix environment, often one can just run ps and see the exact command as it was invoked, including switches and any parameter values that it may have received.

I have a Windows executable that it would be valuable for debugging purposes if I could see just what values were passed in, after it is already running. Can this be done, either with the utilities already present in a Windows default install, or something that I could download?

Comment: Note that, unlike UNIX, Windows properly respects the privacy of the user; that is, only administrators and the user who launched a particular process get to see the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 7 and newer (possibly Vista, but I don't have an install to check), the built-in Task Manager can do this. Go to the `Processes` tab, then `View->Select Columns->Command Line`.

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternals has a handy tool,  process explorer.  One of the column you can show for each process is the commandline.

Sysinternals is provided free from microsoft

[link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can see this from Windows Task Manager, just a few clicks.

1. Right click on taskbar or Ctrl-Alt-Del to open task manager.
2. From the menu **View** > **Select columns** > Check **Command Line**

Answer (score 0):

you can check command line using Task Manager :

[image]